Groupby a df column based on other column and add a default value to everylist
I have an df which has 2 columns lets say Region and Country.
Region      Country
================================
AMER       US
AMER       CANADA
APJ        INDIA
APJ        CHINA

I have grouped the unique Country list for each Region using the code and o/p like below:
df.drop_duplicates().groupby("Region")['Country'].agg(lambda x: sorted(x.unique().tolist())).to_dict()

OUTPUT
{ 'AMER': ['US', 'CANADA'], 'APJ': ['INDIA', 'CHINA'] }

Is there way with to add a default value "ALL" to every list?
=============================================================
EDIT:
I have a similar situation again and really would need some help here.
I have an df which has 3 columns lets say Region, Country and AREA_CODE.
Region      Country     AREA_CODE
===================================
AMER       US             A1
AMER       CANADA         A1
AMER       US             B1
AMER       US             A1

I want to get the output like list of AREA_CODE for each country under each Region with 'ALL' as list value as well. something like
{
  "AMER": {
            "US": ["ALL", "A1", "B1"],
            "CANADA": ["ALL", "A1"]
          }
}

So far i have tried to groupby both region and country column and then tried to group & agg it by AREA_CODE, it is throwing error
df.drop_duplicates().groupby(["Region", "Country"]).groupby("Country")['AREA_CODE'].agg(lambda x: ["ALL"]+sorted(x.unique().tolist())).to_dict()

Could someone kindly help me with this.
Thanks,

You can add ['ALL'] in your agg:
(df.drop_duplicates().groupby("Region")['Country']
   .agg(lambda x: sorted(x.unique().tolist())+['ALL'])
   .to_dict()
)

Also note you you don't really need agg and could use a dictionary comprehension:
out = {k: sorted(v.unique().tolist())+['ALL']
       for k, v in df.drop_duplicates().groupby("Region")['Country']}

Output:
{'AMER': ['CANADA', 'US', 'ALL'], 'APJ': ['CHINA', 'INDIA', 'ALL']}


Is there a way to add the 'ALL' at the start of the list instead of at the end ?

Yes, use lambda x: ['ALL']+sorted(x.unique().tolist()) in place of lambda x: sorted(x.unique().tolist())+['ALL']

Hey @mozway, i have edited the above question with a similar ask, could you pls help me with the same also

@SM079 it's not ok to change questions and unaccept answers. Please ask a new question, since it's different. You can reference this one.

i am really sorry.. could you pls help me out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79158209/groupby-a-df-column-based-on-2-other-columns
