Groupby a df column based on 2 other columns
I have an df which has 3 columns lets say Region, Country and AREA_CODE.
Region      Country     AREA_CODE
===================================
AMER       US             A1
AMER       CANADA         A1
AMER       US             B1
AMER       US             A1

I want to get the output like list of AREA_CODE for each country under each Region with 'ALL' as list value as well. something like
{
  "AMER": {
            "US": ["ALL", "A1", "B1"],
            "CANADA": ["ALL", "A1"]
          }
}

So far i have tried to groupby both region and country column and then tried to group & agg it by AREA_CODE, it is throwing error
df.drop_duplicates().groupby(["Region", "Country"]).groupby("Country")['AREA_CODE'].agg(lambda x: ["ALL"]+sorted(x.unique().tolist())).to_dict()

Could someone kindly help me with this.
Thanks,

Please update your example to demonstrate what should happen if you have other regions. I presume this should create independent dictionaries with only the country of the region.

In order to have an extra level of dictionary nesting, you need to perform an additional groupby.
This is most easily done in a dictionary comprehension:
out = {k: {k2: ['ALL']+sorted(v2.unique().tolist())
           for k2, v2 in v.groupby('Country')['AREA_CODE']
          }
       for k, v in df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Region')
      }

Or using a single groupby and a for loop:
out = {}

for (k1, k2), v in df.groupby(['Region', 'Country'])['AREA_CODE']:
    out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = ['ALL']+sorted(v.unique())

Output:
{'AMER': {'CANADA': ['ALL', 'A1'],
          'US': ['ALL', 'A1', 'B1'],
         },
}

Example with more regions:
# input
  Region Country AREA_CODE
0   AMER      US        A1
1   AMER  CANADA        A1
2   AMER      US        B1
3   AMER      US        A1
4   ASIA   INDIA        C1

# output
{'AMER': {'CANADA': ['ALL', 'A1'], 'US': ['ALL', 'A1', 'B1']},
 'ASIA': {'INDIA': ['ALL', 'C1']}}


Another possible solution, which proceeds as follows:

First, it groups df by the 'Region' and 'Country' columns using groupby by Region and Country.
The agg(list) function aggregates the grouped data into lists.
The unstack(0) method pivots the Region level of the index to columns, creating a hierarchical column index.
The droplevel(0, axis=1) function removes the Region level from the column index.
Finally, to_dict converts the dataframe into a dictionary.

(df.groupby(['Region', 'Country'])
 .agg(list).unstack(0).droplevel(0, axis=1).to_dict())

Output:
{'AMER': {'CANADA': ['A1'], 'US': ['A1', 'B1', 'A1']}}


In case, the dataframe contains more than a single region:
df.groupby('Region').apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby('Country')['AREA_CODE'].apply(list).to_dict(), 
    include_groups=False
).to_dict()

Output:
Uses @mozway's example dataframe (thanks!):
{'AMER': {'CANADA': ['A1'], 'US': ['A1', 'B1', 'A1']},
 'ASIA': {'INDIA': ['C1']}}


Using unstack will most likely cause issues for larger datasets. For instance, if you imagine another region (e.g. ASIA) it will also collect US/CANADA in the inner dictionary, which presumable is unwanted.

Thanks, @mozway, for your comment! Maybe we can circumvent that by using pivot instead of unstack. I will try it out.

It will be the same, the issue is going through a rectangular form. To avoid creating extra groups you need to loop over the unique combinations (either with 2 groupby or with a for loop).

I will think about that.

I have just added a solution that works when there is more than a single region, @mozway.
